# Ignoring punctuation, white space and capital letters in palindrome validation

Tags: c++

So far my program prompts the user to enter a string and then read from start to end and backwards and compares both results. Obviously, if they are equal it's a palindrome, if not - it ain't.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    string input;

    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    cin >> input;

    if (input == string(input.rbegin(), input.rend())) {
        cout << "Yes";
    } else {
        cout << "No";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Question is, how do I omit things like whitespaces, punctuation etc so that I can use sentences and check them if are a palindrome or not?

Comment: You need to preprocess your input string to strip out non-alpha characters and also make all alpha characters the same case.

Comment: Off-topic, but how about `equal(input.begin(), input.end(), input.rend())` to avoid making a temporary string?

Comment: @dwvaxaz In my opinion it is not a good idea to change the original string. I think you shall not change the original string. You only need to say whether it is a palindrome or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just process the input first:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/case_conv.hpp>
#include <cctype>

input.erase(
    std::remove_if(input.begin(), input.end(),
                   [] (char c) { return std::isspace(c) || std::ispunct(c); }),
    input.end()
);
boost::algorithm::to_lower(input);
```